# Trigger an AWS CloudWatch alarm on past data points

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch, alarm

I have CloudWatch metrics that are published asynchronously and sometimes with data points from the past. For example, today, metrics can be published for data points from last week. The [PutMetricData API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_PutMetricData.html) allows this, stating: "You specify the time stamp to be associated with each data point. You can specify time stamps that are as much as two weeks before the current date, and as much as 2 hours after the current day and time."

I also have alarms set up for these metrics. When the metrics exceed a given threshold, I want the alarm to trigger.

This behavior is standard for the most recent data points, but is it possible for the metrics that are published with older timestamps to trigger the alarm as well? For example, I would like the alarm to activate when a data point with a timestamp from last week is published, and the data point value is above the alarm threshold.

Thank you!

---

I am wondering whether I could achieve such behavior with long alarm evaluation periods. But would that make the alarm long to trigger? I want the alarm to trigger as soon as it detect a data point that exceeds the threshold.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do this without any other logic outside of CloudWatch.

If you're doing the `PutMetricData` from a script (bash, Lambda, etc), then maybe you can also include the `SetAlarmState` API call if the Metric Value breached the threshold.

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

THRESHOLD=your-alarm-threshold

aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --namespace $NAMESPACE --metric-data $DATA --metric-name $NAME --timestamp $TIMESTAMP --unit $UNIT --value $VALUE

if [[ $VALUE > $THRESHOLD ]]; then
    aws cloudwatch set-alarm-state --alarm-name $ALARM_NAME  --state-value ALARM --state-reason "Breached Threshold on $TIMESTAMP"

    # or use a different way to notify you instead of CloudWatch alarm, you can just notify yourself from using SNS Publish API.
    aws sns publish --topic-arn $ARN --message "Breached Threshold on $TIMESTAMP"
fi
```

However, you might need to set the Alarm back to OK state. Not sure if CloudWatch will update the alarm state when new metrics comes in.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/set-alarm-state.html